# Running a process from an app started from a Windows 7 service

Tags: c#, .net, service, process

I got a c# windows service which starts an app using this method: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite
This app starts another hidden c# console app which just sends a picture to connected printer and terminates.

The problem is that the second app doesn't work in this case.
If the first app started not from the service everything works fine. If the first app started by the service, printing fails with a strange error about not having anough paper or something.

So this means that the printing app is being started somehow differently. Does anyone have a clue what's going on and how to debug it?

Thanks.